# Why am i not getting the 200+ mbps that the TimeWarner tech's guys laptop got?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I have a dell inspiron 15 model 3542 with a realtek PCIe FE family controller.
My service provider says I should be getting 200+ Mbps.
Their tech guy plugged his windows 7 professional laptop in and got 212mbps.
I am only getting around 30 - 45mbps.
The tech says it's my Windows 8.1 in tablet mode but when i login i always go straight to the desktop.
I have wondered if i am in desktop or in a tablet version of it and if Realtek PCIe FE controller is limiting my speeds, etc.
Can anybody help me get the same speeds that the tech guy got?
Thankyou in advance

Comment: How are you measuring? (Be as precise as possible.)

Answer (score 0):

Realtek network cards - while common - are not generally high performance.  Also, assuming that "FE" means "Fast Ethernet" - no, the theoretical maximum of an FE device is 100 megabits, and you most likely won't get close to that with a Realtek Fast Ethernet nic.  (Can't say more unless we know the model - you may not want do do it for security or privacy reasons, but posting your Dell service tag would allow us to get more details about your exact specs)

You would need a gigabit network interface to be able to get > 100 megabit speeds.

That said, you should be able to get > 30 megabit speeds.   It may be that your network cable is damaged, low quality or prone to Interference or your switch not negotiating a full duplex connection.   That said, see if there is an updated network driver for your network interface - there is every chance that this will improve performance (to 60-70 megabits or thereabouts ?)

I'm not a Windows person, but the bit about "Tablet Mode" sounds like bunk, and I can see no compelling reason it would be true.

Also, it is unclear how you are performing tests.  It is possible that the Techs tests were different to yours and yielding different results.  I guarantee that (for example) if you tested your speeds against a server in New Zealand you will get lower speeds then testing one sitting on the Comcast network in your city.   [  I doubt this is the primary problem if you are getting 45 megabit over wifi ]

Comment: Realtek network cards in my experience are also *very* buggy. Intel's a bit pricier, but they're generally rock solid. And yes, tablet mode sounds like bunk, you're getting bottlenecked by the fast ethernet adaptor. That said, I've never *seen* a pcie fast ethernet adaptor - they're typically pci, and pci adaptors are typically gig-e.

Comment: I have Realtek NICs in my dedicated servers and don’t have any performance problems whatsoever. A little less prejudice wouldn’t hurt. ;)

Comment: Well, I checked the [specs](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15-3542-laptop_Reference%20Guide_en-us.pdf) and it’s indeed a 100 Mbit/s NIC. Hilarious.